# Pass @ObservedObject as protocol to nested view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'll better explain the problem with a small example:

```swift
struct Person: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

class Company: ObservableObject {
    @Published var employees = [Person]()

    func hire(person: Person) { }
}

protocol Employer {
    func hire(person: Person)
}

extension Company: Employer { }

struct CompanyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var company: Company

    var body: some View {
        List(company.employees) { employee in
            PersonView(person: employee, employer: self.company)
        }
    }
}

struct PersonView: View {
    var person: Person
    var employer: Employer

    var body: some View {
        Text(person.name)
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't build, it gives cryptic error messages (likely due to closures being involved):
[image]

Now, the errors go away if either:

- I remove the `@ObservedObject` wrapper - not feasible as I need to observe the changes,
- or I change `PersonView` to require the concrete class: `var employer: Company` - but this breaks the Interface Segregation Principle
- or I add an extra `.self` when instantiating: `PersonView(person: employee, employer: self.company.self)`

All of the above are workarounds, wondering if I'm doing something wrong with the configuration of the parent view. Basically the only viable solution is the 3rd one, but it feels odd to have to add a trailing `.self` just to make the project build.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the type explicit by adding `as Employer`, and open an enhancement request about this through Apple Feedback (I don't think this is necessarily a Swift issue; I suspect it's related to ObservedObject).

```
PersonView(person: employee, employer: self.company as Employer)
```